# Suppose $f: \omega\to\omega_1$ is increasing (i.e., for all $n < m$, $f(n)< f(m)$). Show that there is some $\alpha < \omega_1$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f: \omega\to\omega_1$ is increasing (i.e., for all $n < m$, $f(n)< f(m)$). Show that there is some $\alpha < \omega_1$ such that $f(\omega) \subseteq \alpha$.

I need to find a way of using $f$ to give a countable collection of countable sets and enumerate them using the natural numbers.

Comment: You could look at $\bigcup_{x\in \omega}f(x)$.